# Django 1.5: Remove default language prefix from url in django i18n

Tags: django, django-1.5, django-i18n

I'm using **Django 1.5**.

I have setup internationalization in the project and has set up following variables in the **settings.py** file

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('es', 'Spanish')
)
```

and the **urls.py** file contians

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(app_urlpatterns)),
)
```

But this appends **en** to every URL like

```
https://example.com/en/dashboard
```

I want to hide the default language from the URL pattern.

I tried putting `prefix_default_language=False` in the url pattern

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(app_urlpatterns)),
    prefix_default_language=False
)
```

But this gives error as

```
i18n_patterns() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prefix_default_language'
```

**How can I hide default language prefix from the URL in Django 1.5?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand from [docs](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.5.x/topics/i18n/translation.html#django.conf.urls.i18n.i18n_patterns), by default there is no support for `prefix_default_language` in **django 1.5**. So either you need to discard the idea of using that, or you need to implement that on your own. If you choose latter option, you need to create a new `i18n_patterns` function, also need to update `LocaleRegexURLResolver` inside that. For example:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import LocaleRegexURLResolver


class CustomLocaleRegexURLResolver(LocaleRegexURLResolver):
     def __init__(self, urlconf_name, default_kwargs=None, app_name=None, namespace=None, prefix_default_language=True):
        self.prefix_default_language = prefix_default_language
        super(LocaleRegexURLResolver, self).__init__(None, urlconf_name, default_kwargs, app_name, namespace)

     @property
     def regex(self):
        language_code = get_language()
        if language_code == settings.LANGUAGE_CODE and not self.prefix_default_language:
             return re.compile('^')
        if language_code not in self._regex_dict:
            regex_compiled = re.compile('^%s/' % language_code, re.UNICODE)
            self._regex_dict[language_code] = regex_compiled
        return self._regex_dict[language_code]
```

Now, you need to use `CustomLocaleRegexURLResolver` in custom `i18n_patterns`, like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.core.urlresolvers import LocaleRegexURLResolver

def custom_i18n_patterns(prefix, *args, *kwargs):
    prefix_default_language = kwargs.get('prefix_default_language', True)
    pattern_list = patterns(prefix, *args)
    if not settings.USE_I18N:
        return pattern_list
    return [CustomLocaleRegexURLResolver(pattern_list, prefix_default_language=prefix_default_language)]
```

Finally, use this in your url:

```
urlpatterns += custom_i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(app_urlpatterns)),
    prefix_default_language=False
)
```

Implementation has been done based on code [available here](https://github.com/daoluan/decode-Django/blob/d46a858b45b56de48b0355f50dd9e45402d04cfd/Django-1.5.1/django/conf/urls/i18n.py#L5).

Answer (score 0):

you should take the two seconds to set `USE_I18N = True` in your settings file. Then Django will make some optimizations so as not to load the internationalization machinery. Add `'django.core.context_processors.i18n'` in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting.

## settings.py

```
USE_I18N = True
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"
)
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns += (
    url(r'^', include(app_urlpatterns)),
)
```

Reference: https://django-doc-test1.readthedocs.io/en/stable-1.5.x/topics/i18n/translation.html#overview

Comment: But I want internationalization in my application and just want to remove prefix for default language. For other languages, it is fine.